# Sony Spresenseで作成するコマンド名の長さに制限はありますか？

Tags: spresense

Sony Spresense初心者です。訳あって文字数の多いコマンド名を付けたいのですが、コマンド名の長さに制限はあるでしょうか？

Comment: すみません。ユーザーアプリ名の誤りです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問のタイトルや本文は後からでも [編集] できますので、直接反映してみてください。

Answer (score 3):

NuttShellのコンフィギュレーションにある `READLINE_MAX_EXTCMDS` がDefaultで64なので、
引数含めて64文字までのようです。

```
config READLINE_MAX_EXTCMDS
    int "Maximum external command matches"
    default 64
    depends on READLINE_HAVE_EXTMATCH
    ---help---
        This the maximum number of matching names of external commands that
        will be displayed.
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！助かりました。64文字以内で考えます。

Comment: @user34721 さん、おそらく質問者さんご本人かと思います。質問者さんのアカウントであれば自由にコメントしたり回答を承認したりできます。[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますので、ご検討くださいませ。